# Kindle not connecting to iPhone Wifi hotspot

Tags: iphone, authentication, kindle

Im trying to connect my Kindle HD to my personal hotspot on my iPhone.  I keep getting an authentication problem. How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! This is pretty vague, any chance you can add screenshots or more detailed information?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is see if any other computer or device can work with the hot spot.

Once you're sure your iPhone hot spot works, then you can figure if whatever version of Kindle HD you have has issues or is somehow not working well with whatever version of iOS you run.

Comment: good suggestion (+10)